# Prove that there is an infinite number of values of $n$ for which the biggest prime divisor $p$ of $2^{n}-1$ satisfies $p < 2^{n/2021}-1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation, prime-factorization, natural-numbers

Prove that there is an infinte number of positive integers $n>1$ for which the biggest prime divisor of $2^n-1$ is smaller than $2^\frac{n}{2021}-1$ (which may or may not be integral).

I tried to prove that there is an infinite amount of values of $k,$ such that $n=2^k$ satisfies the statement of the problem.I think that this might work because $2^{2^k}-1=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(1+2^{2^i})$

Now I need to prove that the biggest prime divisor of each term of the product is smaller than $2^\frac{2^k}{2021}-1$.

This is were I got stuck.

Comment: Note:  the header should have $2^n-1$ instead of $2^{n-1}$.  More importantly:  what is the source of this problem?  Many contests and such tend to feature the current year.

Comment: I don't know.I have seen this problem with 1993 instead of 2021 so I think that it is from an 1993 contest but because $2^{10}<1993<2^{11}$ and $2^{10}<2021<2^{11}$ I am pretty sure that it works with 2021 too.

Comment: @lulu Can I edit the header?

Comment: I took care of it, but, yes.  You can always edit your own post.

Comment: Why do you think that it is incorrect?I verefied and I think it is ok so please tell me why it is incorrect.

Comment: The exponents are n,respectively n/2021

Comment: I understand your point but n isn't always divisible by 2021 so $2^a-1$ isn't always an integer.Besides that $2^a-1$ isn't always a prime number so it might be a product of smaller prime divisors that are in fact smaller than $2^{n/2010}-1$

Comment: I'm sorry, for whatever reason I read it as comparing the largest prime divisor of $2^n-1$ with *the largest prime divisor of* $2^a-1$ where $a=n/2021$. My mistake!

Comment: It's ok.I have been thinking about this result : $2^a-1|2^b-1$ if $a|b$ that you have mentioned.I was thinking about chosing n, a product of many distinct prime numbers and then finding a lot of its divisors with the result mentioned before.The problem is that I can't find enough prime divisors, so I can be sure that there aren't any other prime divisors that are too large.Do you have any idea,now that everithing in the statement is clear?

Comment: The problem as stated above is clear. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on how to solve the problem?